# More Pythonic way to loop through a range

Tags: python, range

A friend asked me to make her coding more "pythonic" but I'm pretty new at it myself. This is what I came up with, and I'm a little concerned that it won't hit all of the numbers (6, 7, 8, 9, 10 and 11). I also KNOW that there is a better way, but I just don't know what it is. Can you help?

```
prob = 0
for r in range(6,11):
    prob += binom.pmf(k=r, n=11, p=0.2)
print(‘The probability is {}’,format(prob))
```

Comment: If you want to include 11, you need `range(6, 12)`. Also, `‘` and `’` are not valid quotes. Also, consider using [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum).

Comment: If you want to include `11`, specify `12` as the end of the range.  Other than that, this looks fine to me.

Comment: in the future if you don't know if it will reach all the numbers you can always test ( >> for r in range(6,11): print(r) ) prints 6-10

Comment: _I'm a little concerned that it won't hit all of the numbers (6, 7, 8, 9, 10 and 11)_ Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Thank you all for the information about range!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your code is perfectly pythonic, for what that's worth

You could make it a little more compact and more performant with a list comprehension, the `sum()` function, and an f-string. Also, I took into account that you wanted 11 inclusive, so your range should be from 6 to 12.

```
probs = [binom.pmf(k=r, n=11, p=0.2) for r in range(6, 12)]
print(f'The probability is {sum(probs)}')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use list comprenhension:**

```py
def binom(n,r,p):
  # dummy function
  return n+r+p

prob = sum([binom(r,12, 0.2) for r in range(6,11)])
print(f"The probability is {prob}")
```

**Edit:**
To make 11 inclusive, increase your range to 12

**Edit 2:**
As suggested by [OneCricketeer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/onecricketeer), if only need to compute the sum, you can remove the square brackets, like so:

```
prob = sum(binom(r,12, 0.2) for r in range(6,11))
```

Comment: You can remove the square brackets within the sum

Comment: @OneCricketeer Indeed. If this is used for only computing the sum, the square brackets can/should be removed. They should be kept if computed values need to be saved, assigning the list to a variable and computing the sum after.